# Simple Find & Replace in a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Ok, I have done this a gazillion times in WinForms apps, but this just doesn't work in Metro apps. I'm not going to post the code I have because I believe it will just be confusing (since this same code doesn't work for anybody else's metro apps).

What I am trying to do is allow someone to just enter a string of text into a textbox and then Find that text and highlight/select it in the main textbox. But it seems to be near impossible to accomplish.

I really don't know what to do. I'm beginning to think it's not possible :-/

Comment: showing your code is always a good idea

Comment: Actually, @VladL, previous experience has proven it to be a very bad idea when you know that the code is not right for the job. All it ends up doing is causing confusion, and pointless comments like "Why are you using this code?" or similar comments related to the code, which deters everybody else from the actual problem.

Comment: Looks like you are talking not about Stackoverflow. Why should someone write full code for you then your code maybe needs only a small improvement? In most cases something like "I've tried a lot but nothing is working" means that you don't want to do your job and expecting that someone will do it for you. So please show the code which should be improved

Answer (score 0):

You should check [RichEditBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR227548)

To select your text just use:

```
var sel = myRichEdit.Document.Selection;
    sel.StartPosition = 0;
    sel.EndPosition = 10;
```

Just replace the values with your selection.
To search specyfic text in your RichEditBox just use String method [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/k8b1470s.aspx). This method sould return index of searched value.